# Do we know who is that woman in Bojack Horseman? Let's find out!

Tags: bojack-horseman

In the sweet [BoJack Horseman - "It gets easier" (Season 2 Ending)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2_Mn-qRKjA) YouTube video with the Jogging Baboon, the top 6.7K comment is:

> RIP to the baboon's **wife** - you see her running with him at the beginning of "The BoJack Horseman Show."
> He kept on running.

[Fandom](https://bojackhorseman.fandom.com/wiki/Jogging_Baboon) confirms that:

> There is **an elderly woman** jogging with him.

Jogging Baboo and Elderly woman: What Do we Know about her? Do we Know if she was his wife?? Let's Find Out!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I prefer my phrasing, reflecting the "[Hollywoo Stars and Celebrities: What Do They Know? Do They Know Things?? Let's Find Out!](https://bojackhorseman.fandom.com/wiki/Hollywoo_Stars_and_Celebrities:_What_Do_They_Know%3F_Do_They_Know_Things%3F%3F_Let%27s_Find_Out!)" game from the series. :)

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that was a reference to the show. Fair enough, I'll leave it be, then.